# How to create a UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>

Tags: swift, interop, swift2

I'm working with a C API from Swift and for one of the methods that I need to call I need to give a

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>
```

More Info:

Swift Interface:

```
public func presage_predict(prsg: presage_t, _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> presage_error_code_t
```

Original C:

```
presage_error_code_t presage_predict(presage_t prsg, char*** result);
```

Comment: How is the C function declared and what does it do?

Comment: Swift Interface: public func presage_predict(prsg: presage_t, _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> presage_error_code_t

C: 
    presage_error_code_t presage_predict             (presage_t prsg,
                                                      char*** result);

Comment: @Nykholas, seems you were tried to using presage library for prediction. I am trying to build it on xcode but getting failed. could you teach me how you did it ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Generally, if a function takes a `UnsafePointer<T>` parameter
then you can pass a variable of type `T` as in "inout" parameter with `&`. In your case, `T` is

```
UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>
```

which is the Swift mapping of `char **`. So you can call the C function
as

```
var prediction : UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> = nil
if presage_predict(prsg, &prediction) == PRESAGE_OK { ... }
```

From the documentation and sample code of the Presage library I
understand that this allocates an array of strings and assigns the 
address of this array to the variable pointed to by `prediction`.
To avoid a memory leak, these strings have to be released eventually
with

```
presage_free_string_array(prediction)
```

To demonstrate that this actually works, I have taken the first
part of the demo code at [presage_c_demo.c](http://sourceforge.net/p/presage/presage/ci/5cc9fdca4173334da7d40d41e6ae5ebb4f6f975a/tree/bindings/c/presage_c_demo.c) and translated it
to Swift:

```
// Duplicate the C strings to avoid premature deallocation:
let past = strdup("did you not sa")
let future = strdup("")

func get_past_stream(arg: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> UnsafePointer<Int8> {
    return UnsafePointer(past)
}

func get_future_stream(arg: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> UnsafePointer<Int8> {
    return UnsafePointer(future)
}

var prsg = presage_t()
presage_new(get_past_stream, nil, get_future_stream, nil, &prsg)

var prediction : UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> = nil
if presage_predict(prsg, &prediction) == PRESAGE_OK {

    for var i = 0; prediction[i] != nil; i++ {
        // Convert C string to Swift `String`:
        let pred = String.fromCString(prediction[i])!
        print ("prediction[\(i)]: \(pred)")
    }

    presage_free_string_array(prediction)
}

free(past)
free(future)
```

This actually worked and produced the output

```
prediction[0]: say
prediction[1]: said
prediction[2]: savages
prediction[3]: saw
prediction[4]: sat
prediction[5]: same
```

Comment: I think you missed a UnsafeMutablePointer in the prediction declaration also I got the following error for the string conversion: Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' aka UnsafePointer<Int8> also prediction is not an array

Comment: @Nykholas: I am fairly sure that I did not miss a pointer. I have compiled that code against the presage headers and got no warnings or errors.

Comment: @Nykholas: I have added more information and sample code, hope that helps.

Comment: yeah it compiles, but i think is wrong, because prediction has the wrong signature. you said it's a char** instead of a char*** (according to the header) and again prediction doesn't seem to be an array at all. I copy-pasted you code and it never enters the for cycle:

(lldb) fr v prediction[0]
error: "(Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Int8>>) prediction" is not an array type

Comment: @Nykholas: Very strange, it compiles and runs for me, producing the shown results, no errors or warnings.

Comment: @Nykholas: I did not say that the function takes a `char **` parameter. It takes a `char ***`, which is a pointer to a `char **`.

Comment: weird thing it didn't work exactly what you put.I got an error: A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a func or a literal closure, but I passed the string as arguments and then obtaining them from the closure and it worked!

Comment: var prediction : UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> = nil - 'nil' cannot initialize specified type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>'

Comment: @IgorVasilev: I can not test it currently, but `var prediction : UnsafeMutablePointer?<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>> = nil` should work with the current Swift.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a better way but this runs in playground and defines a value `r` with the type you want:

```
func ptrFromAddress<T>(p:UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
{
   return p
}

var myInt:Int8 = 0
var p = ptrFromAddress(&myInt)
var q = ptrFromAddress(&p)
var r = ptrFromAddress(&q)
```

What's the point of defining `ptrFromAddress`, which seems like it does nothing? My thinking is that the section of the Swift interop book which discusses mutable pointers shows many ways to initialize them by passing some expression as an argument (like `&x`), but does not seem to show corresponding ways where you simply call `UnsafeMutablePointer`'s initializer. So let's define a no-op function just to use those special initialization methods based on argument-passing

#### Update:

While I believe the method above is correct, it was pointed out by @alisoftware in another forum that this seems to be a safer and more idiomatic way to do the same thing:

```
var myInt: Int8 = 0
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&myInt) { (var p) in
  withUnsafeMutablePointer(&p) { (var pp) in
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(&pp) { (var ppp) in
      // Do stuff with ppp which is a UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>
    }
  }
}
```

It's more idiomatic because you're using the function `withUnsafeMutablePointer` which is supplied by the Swift standard library, rather than defining your own helper. It's safer because you are guaranteed that the `UnsafeMutablePointer` is only alive during the extent of the call to the closure (so long as the closure itself does not store the pointer).