# How to convert Swift [Data] to char **

Tags: ios, c, swift, interop, swift5

I'm currently trying to port my Java Android library to Swift. In my Android library I'm using a JNI wrapper for [Jerasure](https://github.com/tsuraan/Jerasure) to call following C method

```
int jerasure_matrix_decode(int k, int m, int w, int *matrix, int row_k_ones, int *erasures, char **data_ptrs, char **coding_ptrs, int size)
```

I have to admit that I'm relatively new to Swift so some of my stuff might be wrong. In my Java code `char **data_ptrs` and `char **coding_ptrs` are actually two dimensional arrays (e.g. byte[][] dataShard = new byte[3][1400]). These two dimensional arrays contain actual video stream data. In my Swift library I store my video stream data in a `[Data]` array so the question is what is the correct way to convert the `[Data]` array to the C `char **` type.

I already tried some things but none of them worked. Currently I have following conversion logic which gives me a *UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer?>?* pointer (*data = [Data]*)

```
let ptr1 = ptrFromAddress(p: &data)
ptr1.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?.self, capacity: data.count) { pp in
    // here pp is UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?
}

func ptrFromAddress<T>(p:UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
{
   return p
}
```

The expected result would be that jerasure is able to restore missing data shards of my [Data] array when calling the `jerasure_matrix_decode` method but instead it completely messes up my [Data] array and accessing it results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS. So I expect this is completely the wrong way.

Documentation in the jerasure.h header file writes following about `data_ptrs`

> data_ptrs = An array of k pointers to data which is size bytes

Edit:

The jerasure library is defining the `data_ptrs` like this

```
#define talloc(type, num) (type *) malloc(sizeof(type)*(num))

char **data;

data = talloc(char *, k);
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  data[i] = talloc(char, sizeof(long)*w);
}
```

So what is the best option to call the `jerasure_matrix_decode` method from swift? Should I use something different than [Data]?

Possible similar question:

1. [How to create a UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687808/how-to-create-a-unsafemutablepointerunsafemutablepointerunsafemutablepointeri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution could be to allocate appropriate memory and fill it with the data.

**Alignment**

The equivalent to `char **` of the C code would be `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>` on Swift side.

In the definition of `data_ptrs` that you show in your question, we see that each data block is to be allocated with malloc.

A property of C malloc is that it does not know which pointer type it will eventually be cast into. Therefore, it guarantees strictest memory alignment:

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

see [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3)

Particularly performance-critical C routines often do not operate byte by byte, but cast to larger numeric types or use [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD).

So, depending on your internal C library implementation, allocating with `UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>.allocate(capacity: columns)` could be problematic, because

> UnsafeMutablePointer provides no automated memory management or alignment guarantees.
> see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer

The alternative could be to use UnsafeMutableRawPointer with an alignment parameter. You can use `MemoryLayout<max_align_t>.alignment` to find out the maximum alignment constraint.

**Populating Data**

An `UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>` would have the advantage that we could use pointer arithmetic. This can be achieved by converting the UnsafeMutableRawPointer to an OpaquePointer and then to an UnsafeMutablePointer. In the code it would then look like this:

```
let colDataRaw = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: cols, alignment: MemoryLayout<max_align_t>.alignment)
let colData = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>(OpaquePointer(colDataRaw))
for x in 0..<cols {
    colData[x] = CChar(bitPattern: dataArray[y][x])
}
```

**Complete Self-contained Test Program**

Your library will probably have certain requirements for the data (e.g. supported matrix dimensions), which I don't know. These must be taken into account, of course. But for a basic technical test we can create an independent test program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrix.h"

void some_matrix_operation(int rows, int cols, char **data_ptrs) {
    printf("C side:\n");
    for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
            printf("%02d ", (unsigned char)data_ptrs[y][x]);
            data_ptrs[y][x] += 100;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

It simply prints the bytes and adds 100 to each byte to be able to verify that the changes arrive on the Swift side.

The corresponding header must be included in the bridge header and looks like this:

```
#ifndef matrix_h
#define matrix_h

void some_matrix_operation(int rows, int cols, char **data_ptrs);

#endif /* matrix_h */
```

On the Swift side, we can put everything in a class called Matrix:

```
import Foundation

class Matrix: CustomStringConvertible {
    let rows: Int
    let cols: Int
    let dataPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>

    init(dataArray: [Data]) {
        guard !dataArray.isEmpty && !dataArray[0].isEmpty else { fatalError("empty data not supported") }
        self.rows = dataArray.count
        self.cols = dataArray[0].count
        self.dataPtr = Self.copyToCMatrix(rows: rows, cols: cols, dataArray: dataArray)
    }
    
    deinit {
        for y in 0..<rows {
            dataPtr[y]?.deallocate()
        }
        dataPtr.deallocate()
    }
    
    var description: String {
        var desc = ""
        for data in dataArray {
            for byte in data {
                desc += "\(byte) "
            }
            desc += "\n"
        }
        return desc
    }
    
    var dataArray: [Data]  {
        var array = [Data]()
        for y in 0..<rows {
            if let ptr = dataPtr[y] {
                array.append(Data(bytes: ptr, count: cols))
            }
        }
        return array
    }

    
    private static func copyToCMatrix(rows: Int, cols: Int, dataArray: [Data]) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?> {
        let dataPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>.allocate(capacity: rows)
        for y in 0..<rows {
            let colDataRaw = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: cols, alignment: MemoryLayout<max_align_t>.alignment)
            let colData = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>(OpaquePointer(colDataRaw))
            dataPtr[y] = colData
            for x in 0..<cols {
                colData[x] = CChar(bitPattern: dataArray[y][x])
            }
        }
        return dataPtr
    }
    
}
```

You can call it as shown here:

```
let example: [[UInt8]] = [
    [ 126, 127, 128, 129],
    [ 130, 131, 132, 133],
    [ 134, 135, 136, 137]
]
let dataArray = example.map { Data($0) }

let matrix = Matrix(dataArray: dataArray)

print("before on Swift side:")
print(matrix)

some_matrix_operation(Int32(matrix.rows), Int32(matrix.cols), matrix.dataPtr)

print("afterwards on Swift side:")
print(matrix)
```

**Test Result**

The test result is as follows and seems to show the expected result.

```
before on Swift side:
126 127 128 129 
130 131 132 133 
134 135 136 137 

C side:
126 127 128 129 
130 131 132 133 
134 135 136 137 

afterwards on Swift side:
226 227 228 229 
230 231 232 233 
234 235 236 237
```

Comment: `dataPtr.advanced(by: y).pointee = colData` can simply be written as `dataPtr[y] = colData` .

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, it is a nicer synatx. I have revised my answer accordingly. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Wow, if I could upvote your answer multiple times I would. I was not expecting such a detailed answer. I got it working in the meantime with another approach but I'm not sure if this is a good way to handle it as I process the pointer outside of the withUnsafeMutableBytes closure and I used additional C helper methods. You can find the example here https://gist.github.com/grill2010/793005c1b80ffbd540c01be8a9837e9b Is this safe? Probably not, isn't it?

Comment: Minor remark: Instead of calling the custom C function  `max_alignment()` you can do `MemoryLayout<max_align_t>.alignment`.

Comment: @grill2010 Yep, Apple explicitly states:  _The byte pointer argument should not be stored and used outside of the lifetime of the call to the closure._

Comment: @StephanSchlecht yeah as I thought, nice thing was that I didn't need to convert anything back into [Data] and it wasn't needed to copy the [Data] which, if I have understood your example correctly, is happening and the original [Data] will still be the same after the some_matrix_operation call?

Comment: @grill2010 Yes, you need to create a new data array and populate it with the result. However, copying the data should not be critical in terms of performance.

Comment: @MartinR I edited the answer to use MemoryLayout. Elegant. Thx again.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht okay thanks very much for your helpful answers. One last question as I also found the warning that Apple says "The byte pointer argument should not be stored and used outside of the lifetime of the call to the closure" why is this the case actually? I know it's "unsafe" to work with pointers but I did this before in other programming languages and Apple doesn't provide any other way than using this closure mechanism to access a pointer, is this because Swift memory management could reallocate/ move the actual pointer outside the closure?

Comment: @grill2010 What Apple does underneath, whether they reallocate or just make it temporary available, whether they need to sync internal state or whether it's safe for certain classes to use it, etc. is speculation.  But using it outside of the closure is undefined behavior. This can manifest itself in errors that are often difficult to track down.

In general, the term "unsafe" in Swift refers to working directly with memory instead of objects (with benefits such as memory management, type safety, etc.).  In C#, for example, the term "unmanaged" is used, which may be more appropriate.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht yeah probably speculation and I agree that the word "unmanaged" would be more appropriate. But for me your answer works and it seems it is the only real good way to make it work. Only one small minor correction the "colData[x] = CChar(dataArray[y][x])" should be replaced with colData[x] = CChar(Int8(bitPattern: dataArray[y][x])) as it would lead to "Not enough bits to represent the passed value" (signed, unsigned memory problem), but could you not then just use "colData[x] = Int8(bitPattern: dataArray[y][x])" and return a UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>

Comment: Good point. By the way, CChar is a type alias to Int8, so both types are interchangeable. So you can either use CChar(bitPattern:) or Int8(bitPattern:). I've included it in the answer, and also added the ability to convert the data back to a data array in the Matrix class. It is called `dataArray`.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht thanks again for your really useful answers. Very very useful for a Swift beginner like me.